# Play framework sbt docker:publishLocal showing Errors

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I created a new project from play template https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/NewApplication

But when i run sbt docker:publishLocal i get the below errors . However the images are correctly created. Why is this happening any idea

```
[error] #1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
[error] #1 sha256:53a6b23aa3772e7eb99dd566338d753cd5d899249093b40f32adc07835722c13
[error] #1 transferring dockerfile: 526B 0.0s done
[error] #1 DONE 0.0s
[error] #2 [internal] load .dockerignore
[error] #2 sha256:350be12e6072f0d32b32ceba390671a7665ca3512bbcb5eda1720e410e991677
[error] #2 transferring context: 2B done
[error] #2 DONE 0.0s
[error] #3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:8
[error] #3 sha256:14e0bc6c3291bf6e9518cae71297359a975961fa3661ed2418806c53bda51bdd
[error] #3 DONE 1.6s
[error] #4 [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:8@sha256:5d1f52c5be872d4d460033f37490817698925737c049d987bb8ff834e3a558c3
[error] #4 sha256:7eed1880b472f1d1d2076a94c5e1fba6b6aeb0738f2b045e7a8aa9ade5add0df
[error] #4 DONE 0.0s
[error] #7 [internal] load build context
[error] #7 sha256:5068512a79803fdbfc3ee2ce534ba7f99fc6b7a060e41052287faaa6634584c5
[error] #7 transferring context: 9.32MB 0.3s done
[error] #7 DONE 0.3s
[error] #5 [2/4] RUN id -u demiourgos728 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || (( getent group 0 1>/dev/null 2>&1 || ( type groupadd 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && groupadd -g 0 root || addgroup -g 0 -S root )) && ( type useradd 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && useradd --system --create-home --uid 1001 --gid 0 demiourgos728 || adduser -S -u 1001 -G root demiourgos728 ))
[error] #5 sha256:8751f82b5efd290415e61279d9f0ad6cfafc2b41b1ac753314f9624e08a09417
[error] #5 CACHED
[error] #6 [3/4] WORKDIR /opt/docker
[error] #6 sha256:5ade8249febc039cbe5475398c41ba29e337327601620ca635630de757c83c82
[error] #6 CACHED
[error] #8 [4/4] COPY --chown=demiourgos728:root opt /opt
[error] #8 sha256:c2453d0d1ed92baf5baf84b413099df2a62a95dcc3dfb6c95da29392eed87ced
[error] #8 CACHED
[error] #9 exporting to image
[error] #9 sha256:e8c613e07b0b7ff33893b694f7759a10d42e180f2b4dc349fb57dc6b71dcab00
[error] #9 exporting layers done
[error] #9 writing image sha256:2dca717a84b648196cf83e74e164aaf3fe9ad72568a3ce6d1589d7efff7ea061 done
[error] #9 naming to docker.io/library/restaurant_api:1.0-SNAPSHOT done
[error] #9 DONE 0.0s
```

Comment: Any other error message? THis looks more like a debug output

Comment: They're not errors. See https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/1412

Answer (score 2):

These are not error messages. Docker prints some of its output to stderr and the internal logger renders it as an error.

No Error though. There are a few discussions on GitHub ☺️

Cheers,
Muki